# How to mine my contract in testrpc

Tags: testrpc

After learning to create and deploy my contract to my testrpc, now I can't figure out how to get my contract mined.

I created my contract and my testrpc is up and running. But my solidity online compiler shows me *"Waiting for transaction to be mined..."*

How can I start to mine blocks in my testrpc? (Metamask shows *Contract published*)

Answer (score 1):

You can force a block to be mined with `evm_mine`

See [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc).

Comment: because i am new to dApp developpment, how do i use this method? Insert this method in the cmd?

Comment: See [Write commands in console](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19059/testrpc-how-to-write-commands-in-console/19065) for a console on testrpc.

Comment: when i enter "evm_mine" JS geth Console replies 'evm_mine" is not defined. Do i have to add some sort of lib?